# How to read environment variables into react js app?

Tags: reactjs, environment-variables

We are trying to read environment variables into reacts js app. Could you let know the process?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

install dotnev:

```
npm install dotenv --save
```

Then create a .env file at the root directory of your application

To start using it you should add this

```
require('dotenv').config()
```

Answer (score 0):

In my real web apps, I like `dotenv-webpack` plugin which works best for web app and it basically use both `dotenv` + `webpack.DefinePlugin` under the hood. The way of use is to simply define `.env` then set it as loader in `webpack.config.js`:

```
const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack');
 
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    new Dotenv({ path: '/path/to/your/.env' })
  ]
};
```